# Why is this a senseful notion of stability? Whyt is the intuition behind this idea of stability?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stability-theory

Let $\xi=x-ct$. Moreover, let $U(\xi)$ be a travelling wave solution of a PDE. Suppose that $U(\xi,t)$ is a solution of a PDE.

The travelling wave $U(\xi)$ is called stable (with respect to the PDE) if there is a neighborhood $N$ of it, such that for a solution $U(\xi,t)$ whose initial value $U(\xi,0)$ is within $N$,  there exists some $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\lVert U(\xi,t)-U(\xi+k)\rVert\to 0~\text{ as }t\to+\infty.
$$

*In other words, a travelling wave $U(\xi)$ is stable, if each solution whose initial values are sufficiently close to it (in some norm), converges to a translate travelling wave $U(\cdot +k)$ as $t\to +\infty$.*

> I am wondering a bit why this reflects a stable behaviour of $U(\xi)$ since the translate travelling wave $U(\cdot +k)$ can be very far away from $U(\xi)$, or not? Maybe this is not possible because of the wave structure, that is, after some time there is the next "maximum" (when the wave is starting again) and so maybe the definition tells us that, indeed, this means that the solution will be close to $U(\xi)$ as $t\to\infty$ if it is close to some translate of it. Is this the reason why it is a stable behaviour?

In other words: If I think of a typical wave form, then, when a solution starts near a wave and then, as $t\to\infty$, it is near some translate of the wave, this implies that it is somewhere between to "maxima" of the wave, so it is quite near to the original wave again?

But what if two maxima of the wave are far away from each other? Then being close to some translate of the wave does not need to mean being near the original wave? Maybe my intuition is wrong.

Comment: I suppose this concerns nonlinear waves like solitons that can converge to stable shapes with very structured relations between peak amplitude, peak with and wave speed.  Then a small disturbance might shift the phase, location, but still converge to the same shape and speed.

Comment: The background of my question is FitzHugh-Nagumo, i.e. propagation in neurons, if this helps.

Comment: I am just think about the situation if the wave is supposed to be in some small neighborhood. Then translates of it should be in this small neighborhood, too. So if a solution start near the wave and then, as $t\to +\infty$, is near some translate of this wave, it should be in the neighborhood again and so near the original wave. Is this some situation to think of?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read this review article:

B Sandstede, *Stability of travelling waves*, in B. Fiedler (ed), 'Handbook of Dynamical Systems', vol 2 (2002), ch. 18, pp 983-1055, [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S1874-575X(02)80039-X).